# Count users with more than X amount of transactions within Y days by date

Tags: postgresql

Scenario: Trying to count more active users for time series analysis. 
Need: With postgreSQL(redshift) Count customers that have more than X unique transactions within Y days from said date, group by date.

How do i achieve this?

Table: orders

| date | user_id | product_id | transaction_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 001 | 003 | 001 |
| 2022-01-02 | 002 | 001 | 002 |
| 2022-03-01 | 003 | 001 | 003 |
| 2022-03-01 | 003 | 002 | 003 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Outcome:

| date | active_customers |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 10 |
| 2022-01-02 | 12 |
| 2022-01-03 | 9 |
| 2022-01-04 | 13 |

Comment: Are you familiar with window functions?  This would be a LAG() window function but you need to prep the data so that each user has a summary of transactions per day.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for pointing to right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use the window functions `LEAD()` and `LAG()` here but this solution may also work for you.

```
WITH data AS
(
    SELECT o.date
         , o.user_id
         , COUNT(o.trans_id) tcount
      FROM orders o
     WHERE o.date BETWEEN o.date - '30 DAYS'::INTERVAL AND o.date -- Y days from given date
     GROUP BY o.date, o.user_id
), user_transaction_count AS
(
    SELECT d.date
         , COUNT(d.user_id) FILTER (WHERE d.tcount > 1) -- X number of transactions 
                              OVER (PARTITION BY d.user_id) user_count
      FROM data d
)
SELECT u.date
     , SUM(u.user_count) active_customers
  FROM user_transaction_count u
 GROUP BY u.date
 ORDER BY u.date
;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/gcO99qsE) is a DBFiddle that demos a couple options.

Comment: Table does have all dates. i meant that query would count amount of customers that have multiple transactions within Y interval on every date. 

So calculation happens on every date. If that makes sense :)

Comment: So let's say the date is `2022-02-02` and the interval is `1 DAY`. In order for a customer to be counted, they need to have at least 2 unique transactions between `2022-02-01` and `2022-02-03`? Or does the customer need to have multiple on every day?

Comment: Yes!
Just like your example.

Date is 2022-02-02 and the interval is 1 DAY. In order for a customer to be counted, they need to have at least 2 unique transactions between 2022-02-01 and **2022-02-02**.

It's okay if customer does have multiple unique transactions per day, but it is not requirement

Comment: I have a couple further questions. Consider a user, `user123`, has two unique transactions only on `2022-02-01`. You want that to count that as `1` for all dates that fall within the date fuzz? Also, with the `1 DAY` interval, are you only looking to count transactions from the given date or earlier, or `1 DAY` "both sides" of the given date? In other words, count anything that is at max `N DAYS` away from the given date, before or after.

Comment: Hopefully i understand your questions correctly. Let's say that i want to calculate all customers that have `3 or more` unique orders within date range. E.g. `date between date-30 and date`. Do this calculation for every date. If `user123` has `3 or more` unique transactions within date range, it is counted as 1. Even if `user123` has `2` unique transaction on a same date and `1` on another date, that falls within the date range, it is counted as 1.

Comment: Mostly there, but since we're grouping by date I'm asking, "which date do you want that count of 1 active user applied to?" All of them? Only the day at which the transaction happened? It's like saying, "For the given date range, was there a user who had more than one transaction? Yes, we found one to count.  Do I increment the count for the given date or increment the count on the date the transaction happened?"

Comment: Increment the count for the given date. Thank you for your patience

Comment: @MikaelBjörkqvist I've updated my answer. Something to consider: if you have a single user complete 2 transactions on one day, you will increment the count for that day BUT that user will also show up as countable for the next 30 days. In essence, on day one did I find that user? Yes. On the next day, I still find that user. And the next, and the next until that user no longer falls within the fuzzy date range of `this` day minus `fuzz`. Hope that makes sense. That's kind of what I was getting at earlier.

Comment: Just tested it out. Seems to be working :) Have to do some validations as i'm quite sure i should get more customers per day as result.

`FILTER` syntax does not work in AWS redshift so i changed it to `COUNT(CASE WHEN d.tcount > 1 THEN d.user_id end) OVER (PARTITION BY d.user_id) user_count`